# In the proof of "Any two bases of a Hilbert space have the same cardinality" in Conway

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> [image]

Would anybody explain why in the infinite case of the proof, "so $\mathscr{F}_e$ is countable"?

---

[image]

Comment: It's Parseval's identity (f): A convergent series has at most countably many nonzero terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jose27's comment, I just found that this is also done by a previous theorem in the book:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get a more complete listing of the reference (e.g. title or ISBN) for those interested in finding this text?

Comment: @ALB: https://www.amazon.com/Course-Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387972455

Comment: much obliged, @Jack !